# SQL Change data of a column where data is the same

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have created this table:

```
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Proces1 CASCADE;
        CREATE TABLE Proces1 AS
        (
        SELECT id_importat AS id_aux, driver_city AS city_aux, 
        driver_state AS state_aux, gender AS g_aux, race AS r_aux
            FROM ImportaViolations
            WHERE id_importat IN (
                SELECT id_importat
                FROM ImportaViolations
                GROUP BY id_importat    
                HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))
            GROUP BY id_importat, driver_city, driver_state, gender, race
        );
```

And using this table I have created this one:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Proces2 CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Proces2 AS 
(
    SELECT id_aux AS id_aux2, city_aux AS city_aux2, state_aux AS state_aux2, 
    g_aux AS g_aux2, r_aux AS r_aux2, rn
        FROM (
              SELECT id_aux, city_aux, state_aux, 
              g_aux, r_aux, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY id_aux ORDER BY 1) AS rn
              FROM Proces1
             ) d
        WHERE rn > 1
    );
```

So, now I want to change data from the Original table called "ImportaViolations", and I want to update the column "id_serial" from this table to the "rn" column of table "Proces2", but only where information is exactly the same.

I have done the next query but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE ImportaViolations
SET id_serial = p2.rn
FROM ImportaViolations iv, Proces2 p2
WHERE (iv.id_importat, iv.driver_city, iv.driver_state, iv.gender, iv.race) IN (
    SELECT id_aux2, city_aux2, state_aux2, g_aux2, r_aux2
    FROM Proces2
);
```

And yes, the column "id_serial" exists on the table ImportaViolations as an empty column (full of null values). Also I have to say that there is no Primary Key on the ImportaViolations table so I don't mind if we set id_serial repeated values on different rows.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `FROM ImportaViolations iv, Proces2 p2` is a carthesian product, and the subquery `FROM Proces2` is uncorrelated.BTW: your intention is not very clear. Do you want to give duplicates a  rank number?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*"

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres's SQL,you don't have to repeat the name of the *target* table (and you could probably do the same work without intermediate temp tables):

---

```
UPDATE ImportaViolations  iv
SET id_serial = p2.rn
FROM Proces2 p2
WHERE iv.id_importat = p2.id_aux2
        AND iv.driver_city = p2.city_aux2
        AND iv.driver_state = p2.state_aux2
        AND iv.gender = p2.g_aux2
        AND iv.race = p2.r_aux2
        ;
```